# Adding a Static, Complex Object to Mongoose/Passport Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I use Mongoose and Passport in my web application for the addition of new users into my MongoDB database. I use Google oauth for registering/signing in. In my user schema, I have the following defined for the google method:

```
//user.js
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        google           : {
            id           : String,
            token        : String,
            access_token : String,
            email        : String,
            name         : String,
            picture      : String,
            nameInfo     : Object,
        }
    });
```

I use the following method for user creation:

```
//passport.js
var newUser          = new User();

                    //newUser.google.token = token;
                    newUser.google.name  = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.google.nameInfo = profile._json.name
                    newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                    newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                    newUser.google.picture = profile._json.image.url + '0';
                    newUser.google.access_token = token;
```

You can see that all this data goes under the "google" array in the top level of my user document. How would I add a new, complex, static array? For example, I want a new array at the top level of document in the following format:

```
newUser.dogs = ["cats":[]}]
```

I need this particular format based on a dependency in how users should look in my web code. I will eventually be adding data to the "cats" array, but it needs to start out empty. When I try varations of this, I'm only able to get the top level array - ex: my document looks like:

```
objectid: 1000,
google: [...],
dogs: []
```

when I need it to look like:

```
objectid: 1000,
google: [...],
dogs: [{"cats":[]}]
```

What do I need to change to my schema, either on the schema design, or the data going into the schema?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set inner embedded docs.

Here it is sample, You can create it like this.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Trigger = new Schema({
    type : {type: String},    
    value: {type: Number}
});

var  Field = new Schema({
    label : {type: String},
    type: {type: String},
    triggers: [Trigger]

});

var  Form = new Schema({
    fields : [Field],
    user_id : {type: String}
});
```